# Hide button on click using React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I currently have a button that when clicked on shows another component, however I want this specific button to also be hidden when it's clicked on. Any idea? Thanks.

```
const [showSecondFields, setShowSecondFields] = React.useState(false);
const onClick = () => setShowSecondFields(true);

const SecondFields = () => (
<div>
<p>Second Component</p>
</div>
);

<button type="button" className="button--secondary" onClick={onClick}>
 Show Component
</button>
{showSecondFields ? <SecondFields /> : null}
```

Comment: You can apply the same idea that you used with `<SecondFields />` but with the button (you'll need to negate the condition or swap the position of its place in the ternary)

Answer (score 3):

If the components are siblings, you can use a [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to switch between them:

```js
const SecondFields = () => (
  <div>
    <p>Second Component</p>
  </div>
);

const Demo = () => {
  const [showSecondFields, setShowSecondFields] = React.useState(false);
  const onClick = () => setShowSecondFields(true);

  return showSecondFields ?
    <SecondFields />
    : (
      <button type="button" className="button--secondary" onClick={onClick}>
       Show Component
      </button>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo />,
  root
)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put both in one [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) condition

This way you can return one component if the condition is true and another
component if the condition is false

Do it this way

```
{!showSecondFields ?   //if condition true
   <button type="button" className="button--secondary" onClick={onClick}>
       Show Component
   </button>
       :  <SecondFields />  //if condition false
}
```

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do something along the lines of this:

```
{!showSecondFields && <button className="button--secondary" onClick={onClick}>
 Show Component
</button>}

{showSecondFields && <SecondFields /> }
```

The first ternary operator shows the button if the condition is false, the second operator shows the fields if the condition is true.